# How to Fill Path with a Brush from an Image

Tags: mfc, gdi+, gdi

I have a question about MFC.
We have an API:

```
Graphics::Fillpath(IN const Brush * brush, IN const GraphicsPath *path)
```

It means we will fill the path with the brush, ex: if path is a triangle, we could fill it will a #FF0000 Brush color.

Thus, I want to have a way to make a brush from Image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Texture Brush
Bitmap^  objBit .... get your image

TextureBrush^ pat = gcnew TextureBrush(objBit);
g->FillPolygon(pat, pt);
pt is your polygon array